# asp.net Web Forms and Web API

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-web-api

I need to build a web service to handle HTTP Form posts (CRUD) using .Net Web API

Although I am aware that the API can be run under WebForms I have heard that type of thing before (see 'Dynamic Data') and then in the reality encountered the need for functional work-arounds, limitations etc.

Has anyone used Web API for CRUD under Web Forms? Any issues?

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking about MVC 4 Web Api?

Comment: MVC 4 - Well, I am asking about Web APi which happens to be bundled with MVC4 but is in fact an entirely independent product and will run under WebForms.

WCF - I think you need to research WCF vs. Asp.Net WebApi, latter is specifcally targeted at RESTful (i.e. non-SOAP) HTTP-based systems, which is what we need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That works just fine. The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/23/using-asp-net-web-api-with-asp-net-web-forms.aspx has a step-by-step guide on how to make that work. As you said in one of your comments, ASP.NET Web API can be used outside of MVC4, and the easiest way to do that is to use NuGet to download the Web API packages only. The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/07/12/creating-asp-net-web-apis-on-azure-web-sites.aspx does that (it shows Web APIs being used in an empty web application, but the same applies to web forms as well).

Comment: Thanks for the NuGet link (and the reassurance) guess we'll plunge in!